# Using a switching DC-DC converter in high dynamic range current/voltage sensing

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, voltage-measurement, interference, current-sensing

I'm thinking of making a power meter circuit which will have a high-side current-sensing amp ([LTC6102](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6102fe.pdf)), a resistive voltage divider for sensing the voltage, a dual op-amp ([OPA2365](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2365.pdf)) as a buffer for the current and voltage signals, a 2 channel simultaneously sampling ADC([LTC1407](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1407fb.pdf)), an FPGA for multiplying and keeping a running sum and a blue-tooth UART module for transmitting to a phone.

The ADC and the rest of the digital circuit will be powered from 3.3V, and will draw 70mA.
This will be measuring an e-bike's consumed power with the maximum supply voltage of 54.6V.
I would use a liner regulator but then I need a radiator because I need to dissipate 3.5W considering the high voltage drop.

So I'm considering using one of these DC-DC converters with a built-in inductor to save space with less dissipated power.

My concern with these switching converters is noise.

I can estimate the impact of the power supply ripple based on the converter's specs and the PSRRs of the op-amp and the ADC (the current-sense amp will powered directly from the supply)

What I don't know is how to estimate is the impact of the radiated EM noise from the inductor in the converter.

My understanding is that when it comes to EM-induced noise I should be concerned about the places with low currents/high input impedances.

In my case these are the connections:

1. from the output of the current-sense amp to the buffer op-amp (1LSB
   is 2.5V/4096=610uV or 1mA/4096=244nA for the current sense amp's
   output)
2. from the resistive divider to the buffer op-amp (same 610uV LSB)

I understand that the actual currents into the op-amp inputs will be lower, but not sure how to estimate those.

This might be a broad question but as a ball-park estimate is 0.5 LSB of noise achievable in my case with a switching DC-DC converter considering the EM noise from the inductor of the converter?

(Now I'm thinking maybe the bluetooth module is a bigger EMI concern)

Comment: After searching for actual DC-DC converter modules it looks like they are relatively rare with such a high input voltage (and quite bulky, comparable to the 40x40mm heat-sink I was considering), so I may have to use a linear regulator with a heat-sink after all just for this reason...